# How to make a graph to represent mean, standard derivation, maximum and minimum values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, plotly

I want to make a graph with monthly data: mean, standard deviation and maximum and minimum values.
X axis would be my months and I would like to represent my mean with dots, squares and cross, for exemple and my standard deviation represented by delimited vertical lines in the mean symbols.
And still, represent my maximum and minimum values by an area.

I would like to plot 3 different periods: 1961-1990, 1990-2010 and 1961-2010.

Is it possible?

Some data:

```
Mês;Mean1;Std1;Min1;Max1;Mean2;Std2;Min2;Max2;Mean3;Std3;Min3;Max3
Jan;25.45;2.04;13.05;27.50;25.83;1.94;14.01;27.85;25.54;2.03;13.24;27.58
Feb;25.74;2.09;13.02;27.85;26.16;2.01;13.95;28.16;25.92;2.04;13.58;27.99
Mar;25.01;2.13;12.12;27.27;25.35;2.14;12.41;27.67;25.16;2.07;12.68;27.45
Apr;23.16;2.19;9.89;25.48;23.81;2.35;9.62;26.35;23.51;2.17;10.46;25.90
May;21.17;2.21;7.99;23.59;21.31;2.29;7.54;23.88;21.18;2.23;7.84;23.67
Jun;19.88;2.26;6.37;22.34;20.15;2.25;6.65;22.65;20.00;2.26;6.42;22.47
Jul;19.41;2.27;5.78;21.79;19.96;2.10;7.34;22.25;19.60;2.22;6.24;22.02
Aug;20.39;2.10;7.73;22.64;20.75;2.03;8.56;23.00;20.53;2.09;7.93;22.80
Sep;21.08;1.96;9.26;23.29;21.66;1.58;12.21;23.53;21.33;1.91;9.84;23.53
Oct;22.19;1.81;11.33;24.32;23.17;1.62;13.40;25.00;22.60;1.79;11.92;24.76
Nov;23.42;1.90;11.94;25.52;23.89;1.64;13.96;25.68;23.60;1.82;12.63;25.67
Dec;24.39;1.98;12.39;26.39;25.17;1.99;13.07;27.54;24.67;1.94;12.93;26.73
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Yes that is indeed possible.

Long answer:

Here is how you could do it:

Assuming that the data you posted is in some data.frame called `df`:

```
head(df)
```

```
  Mês Mean1 Std1  Min1  Max1 Mean2 Std2  Min2  Max2 Mean3 Std3  Min3  Max3
1 Jan 25.45 2.04 13.05 27.50 25.83 1.94 14.01 27.85 25.54 2.03 13.24 27.58
2 Feb 25.74 2.09 13.02 27.85 26.16 2.01 13.95 28.16 25.92 2.04 13.58 27.99
3 Mar 25.01 2.13 12.12 27.27 25.35 2.14 12.41 27.67 25.16 2.07 12.68 27.45
4 Apr 23.16 2.19  9.89 25.48 23.81 2.35  9.62 26.35 23.51 2.17 10.46 25.90
5 May 21.17 2.21  7.99 23.59 21.31 2.29  7.54 23.88 21.18 2.23  7.84 23.67
6 Jun 19.88 2.26  6.37 22.34 20.15 2.25  6.65 22.65 20.00 2.26  6.42 22.47
```

You first want to convert it from a wide format to a long format, meaning that we want each observation to have its own row. Perhaps someone with more tidyverse experience can do this in a more elegant way, but this is how I would do that:

```
# First we melt the dataframe
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "Mês")

# Then we get a grouping variable from the column "variable"
df2$variable <- as.character(df2$variable)
df2$group <- substr(df2$variable, nchar(df2$variable), nchar(df2$variable))

# And we remove the trailing number from the variable
df2$variable <- substr(df2$variable, 1, nchar(df2$variable) - 1)
```

This is what the data will look like at this point:

```
head(df2)
```

```
  Mês variable value group
1 Jan     Mean 25.45     1
2 Feb     Mean 25.74     1
3 Mar     Mean 25.01     1
4 Apr     Mean 23.16     1
5 May     Mean 21.17     1
6 Jun     Mean 19.88     1
```

We still need the means, standard deviations, minima and maxima to be on the same row, so we are going to un-melt (cast) the data by each group:

```
# First we split by group
df2 <- split(df2, df2$group)

# Then, we loop over the data and cast the data
df2 <- lapply(seq(df2), function(i){
  dat <- df2[[i]]
  cbind(reshape2::dcast(dat, Mês ~ variable), group = i)
})

# And finally combine the data.frame back together
df2 <- do.call(rbind, df2)
```

Now the data should look like this:

```
head(df2)
```

```
  Mês   Max  Mean   Min  Std group
1 Jan 27.50 25.45 13.05 2.04     1
2 Feb 27.85 25.74 13.02 2.09     1
3 Mar 27.27 25.01 12.12 2.13     1
4 Apr 25.48 23.16  9.89 2.19     1
5 May 23.59 21.17  7.99 2.21     1
6 Jun 22.34 19.88  6.37 2.26     1
```

Data in this format is the easiest to plot with. We'll do that as follows:

```
# First we define all shared aesthetics in the main 'ggplot'-call:
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Mês, 
                group = as.factor(group), 
                colour = as.factor(group))) +
  # Then as lowest layer, we want that area spanning 'Min' to 'Max'
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Min, 
                  ymax = Max, 
                  fill = as.factor(group)), alpha = 0.1) +
  # Then we want our means displayed as points
  geom_point(aes(y = Mean, shape = as.factor(group))) +
  # The standard deviation as line segments with an arrowhead
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Mês, 
                   y = Mean - Std, 
                   yend = Mean + Std),
               arrow = arrow(angle = 90, ends = "both", length = unit(2, "mm"))) +
  # Finally we tell that our point shapes should be dots, squares and crosses
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 15, 4))
```

And in my hands this yielded the following:

[image]

Now, as a last tip: if you want more people to help you or get help quicker, it is easiest to give them some data to play around with that they can copy-paste directly in R:

```
dput(df)
```

```
structure(list(Mês = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", 
"Dec"), class = "factor"), Mean1 = c(25.45, 25.74, 25.01, 23.16, 
21.17, 19.88, 19.41, 20.39, 21.08, 22.19, 23.42, 24.39), Std1 = c(2.04, 
2.09, 2.13, 2.19, 2.21, 2.26, 2.27, 2.1, 1.96, 1.81, 1.9, 1.98
), Min1 = c(13.05, 13.02, 12.12, 9.89, 7.99, 6.37, 5.78, 7.73, 
9.26, 11.33, 11.94, 12.39), Max1 = c(27.5, 27.85, 27.27, 25.48, 
23.59, 22.34, 21.79, 22.64, 23.29, 24.32, 25.52, 26.39), Mean2 = c(25.83, 
26.16, 25.35, 23.81, 21.31, 20.15, 19.96, 20.75, 21.66, 23.17, 
23.89, 25.17), Std2 = c(1.94, 2.01, 2.14, 2.35, 2.29, 2.25, 2.1, 
2.03, 1.58, 1.62, 1.64, 1.99), Min2 = c(14.01, 13.95, 12.41, 
9.62, 7.54, 6.65, 7.34, 8.56, 12.21, 13.4, 13.96, 13.07), Max2 = c(27.85, 
28.16, 27.67, 26.35, 23.88, 22.65, 22.25, 23, 23.53, 25, 25.68, 
27.54), Mean3 = c(25.54, 25.92, 25.16, 23.51, 21.18, 20, 19.6, 
20.53, 21.33, 22.6, 23.6, 24.67), Std3 = c(2.03, 2.04, 2.07, 
2.17, 2.23, 2.26, 2.22, 2.09, 1.91, 1.79, 1.82, 1.94), Min3 = c(13.24, 
13.58, 12.68, 10.46, 7.84, 6.42, 6.24, 7.93, 9.84, 11.92, 12.63, 
12.93), Max3 = c(27.58, 27.99, 27.45, 25.9, 23.67, 22.47, 22.02, 
22.8, 23.53, 24.76, 25.67, 26.73)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```